# TitlePageIndicator below ViewPager

Tags: java, android

I searched a lot but couldn't find a answer for this question:
Is there any way to use a TitlePageIndicator below the ViewPager?

I tried the reverse order in .xml but got that:

```
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.totvs.android/br.com.totvs.android.ecm.activity.TelaPrincipalActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at br.com.totvs.android.ecm.activity.TelaPrincipalActivity.onCreate(TelaPrincipalActivity.java:56)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     ... 11 more
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at br.com.totvs.android.ecm.fragment.TabFragment.onCreateView(TabFragment.java:36)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:845)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1058)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1156)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:270)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
04-24 19:30:30.288: E/AndroidRuntime(3338):     ... 18 more
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What TitlePageIndicator are you using? The one from Jake Wharton?

Comment: Please format it as a code, so it's easier to read

Comment: Oppsie, you're right, I get a ClassCastException too... I'll try to look into the matter and let you know, unless someone smarter answers;)

Comment: Do a Project > Clean in Eclipse or an `ant clean` from the command line and see if it clears up your problem.

Comment: Well it does for me. CommonsWare - always on duty:)

Comment: sorry about the code, i'm new here. Clear doesn't help.. i'm getting a super weird error on pager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager); - note: node is working if I put webview below titlebar

Comment: ... ok, well what's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably depends on what type of TitlePageIndicator you're using. But all of the version I've heard of (including probably the most popular one from Jake Wharton) are just views, which you can put anywhere you want.

So you can just inflate such a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />



</LinearLayout>
```

And an extremely important note from Commonsware. Project->Clean

Comment: The advice by CommonsWare worked for me, so I'll leave the answer for someone else. It's weird that it didn't work for you. Do you still get ClassCastException? Maybe restart Eclipse?